# I want to create a global MediaPlayer that will keep playing no matter which layout is displayed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Instead of creating one in my menu class, I'd like to create a global one outside of the menu class that I can call to keep the sound playing no matter which activity is started. I'm a noob to java, but I have searched and can't find a solution. Here is my "menu" activity. As you can see my MediaPlayer snd is local so it gets paused when the onPause method gets called.

```
    public class Menu extends Activity{

MediaPlayer snd;
ToggleButton btnSound;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    snd = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bgmusic);
    snd.start();
    btnSound = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tglSound);

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    snd.pause();
}
```

Comment: use a service for this purpose. https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/60/servicesdemo_using_android_services

Comment: using a service will do for this

Answer (score 3):

The best way to implement your requirement is using a service. You can start a service while the app is intialised. Inside the service start a mediaplayer and start playing. So evenif you are navigating to next or other activities the media will keep playing. You can also give property to the service when to start ad stop. Isted of pausing or stoping mediaplayer you can just stop the service so that the mediplayer will also stop playing. Hope this [link](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/60/servicesdemo_using_android_services) will help you for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem lies in the Android reference:

[MediaPlayback](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

> If you want your media to play in the background even when your
>   application is not onscreen—that is, you want it to continue playing
>   while the user is interacting with other applications—then you must
>   start a Service and control the MediaPlayer instance from there. You
>   should be careful about this setup, because the user and the system
>   have expectations about how an application running a background
>   service should interact with the rest of the system. If your
>   application does not fulfil those expectations, the user may have a
>   bad experience. This section describes the main issues that you should
>   be aware of and offers suggestions about how to approach them.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service like this snippet:

```
public class whatEverYourServiceName extends Service{


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
super.onStart(intent, startId);

//Add your code here mate

}


@Override
public void onDestroy(){
super.onDestroy();

//Add what do you want to do here when the service is stop like do a backflip
snd.pause();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

return null;
}

}
```

Then call it using this

```
Intent it = new Intent();
it.setAction("your.package.name.whatEverYourServiceName");
startService(it);
```

Then add this to your manifest

```
 <service
    android:name="your.package.name.whatEverYourServiceName"
    android:label="Your Service Homie"
    android:process=":my_process" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="your.package.name.whatEverYourServiceName" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

To stop the sound just stop the service using this

```
stopService(new Intent(this, whatEverYourServiceName.class));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Instead of a service, I would rather use a global MediaPlayer and ToggleButton. I want to be able to tell if the ToggleButton is checked no matter which activity or content view I'm on and play the global MediaPlayer.

Comment: Don't use "a global MediaPlayer". Use a Service. Store the value of the Toggle Button in the service and either Bind the service to an activity if you need to access the ToggleButton or extend the mediaplayer to have an extra field (and use that from your service). There are multiple ways to solve this, using a "global mediaplayer" is perhaps the worst idea :)